Want to call a WebService (WSDL is available) with spring boot 3.2.4 JDK 17
I get really heart attack, why it is so complex.
Want to call a WebService URL where I need to send SOAP Request from Spring Boot 3.2.4 with Basic Authentication and JDK 17.
To get the WSDL it is normally also required to send authentication. But if this is too difficult I have the WSDL.
The Java Classes with cxf are already generated. I just want to call the method like:
navisionService = new ESB2NAVInterface("WSDL File or URL");
navisionService.setAuthentication("User", "Password", "ProductionURL");
navisionService.getPrice("12345", 2024-04-05");

Why is this so complex with callbacks and Interfaces bunch. You can't read the code.
Who can provide a full sample ?
I receive always 401 not authorized.
I created one Class with @Configuration to reflect the Conduit. It worked only one time.
